# Particles moving randomly in a 2D plane

Tags: particle-physics, collision, kinetic-theory

There is a circular plane which has a large number of small particles set to move randomly in different directions with same speed. I am supposed to check whether this is equivalent to a situation wherin the particles move only in the radial direction, as opposed to velocities in random directions. .

From what I know, the particles trace a line in a small interval $\triangle$t with distance traversed V$\triangle$t before an elastic collision and changes velocity after collision,but the line keeps changing its direction.So the overall path traversed by a particle wouldn't be radial, right? Will it change if the average motion is considered? If or if not, how am I supposed to visualize the situation then?

Comment: "I am supposed to investigate if the notion of them moving radially changes the model of the situation" - I don't understand...

Comment: @lemon I have edited it accordingly. Sorry for my terrible wording

Comment: "whether this is equivalent" - equivalent in what sense exactly? What is it you intend to measure? The collision rate (i.e. pressure)?

Comment: When you say "move only in the radial direction", do you mean they only move away from the center or do you mean they can move both away and towards the center? What do you mean by equivalent?

Comment: @Crimson Actually I have assumed that they can move both radially inward as well as outward. I want to see if it is the same as when they move randomly

Answer (score 0):

Your description lacks a proper definition of how the particles are distributed and what their degrees of freedom are. And above all it misses a description of what type of behavioral change you are looking for.

If I would guess what you mean, the particles would behave like the ornamental beads kids have on the spokes of their bikes, which give a distinct rattling sound. Only in your case the wheel will not rotate and the beads will move due to thermal energy. The behavior will differ strongly from the case with free particles. Mainly because it becomes harder for the particles to pass each other. Two nearby particles can only pass each other far away from the center. The movement of the particles on nearby spokes will therefore be correlated, while in the free-particle case the movement of individual particles is largely independent.

This is an effect which happens often when you go to (pseudo) 1D systems. Interestingly, if you confine strongly interacting electrons in a solid to a 1D system, their interactions can lead to a separation of the electron's charge and their spin. (see Luttinger liquid)